# PHP - Pass a variable to a function, even if undefined

Tags: php

I have the following snippet:

```
// Some post is made and I have access to it using Input::get('name_of_field');
if (Input::has('optionalField'))
{
    $thisVariable = myMagicalFunction();
}

// more operation
// being performed

ultimateFunction($thisVariable);

return true;
```

As you can see, `$thisVariable` may sometimes not be set, and so the `ultimateFunction($thisVariable)` may sometimes return error saying the variable is undefined. I can of course use

```
if (isset($thisVariable)) ultimateFunction($thisVariable);
```

But is there a way to force pass the variable anyhow without checking if it is set? I will then check if it is set inside `ultimateFunction`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to just declare the variable before it is used:-

```
$thisVariable = null;
if (Input::has('optionalField'))
{
    $thisVariable = myMagicalFunction();
}

// more operation
// being performed

ultimateFunction($thisVariable);

return true;
```

Comment: I know, I wanted to skip that one line! I guess I shouldn't then.

Comment: @Kousha you definitelly shouldn't. The best approach is to create PHP code that have no warnings or notices.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the error with `@`, so:

```
ultimateFunction(@$thisVariable);
```

But it's better to check first. I personally use `@` all the time. It's bad practice.

Comment: I down voted this for recommending the use of error suppression. It is bad practice and worse advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is at best a hack to suppress your error this way. You are ignoring warnings and writing code which is not optimized. Even though it saves you a bit of time, I strongly suggest you avoid doing this.

Ideally, create a service container for $_GET and $_POST which performs this check for you. It can return null if it does not exist.

Alternatively, a procedural answer is something like this:

```
function formGet($input) {
    if(isset($_GET[$input])) {
        return $_GET[$input];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you can simply input your data using `formGet($input)`.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use PHP's error control operator (at-sign):

```
// ...
ultimateFunction(@$thisVariable);
```

There will be `null` force-passed as the `ultimateFunction`'s first argument and inside function you will be able to normally check with `isset()` or `empty()` whether variable was passed.

But if it is possible, that does not mean you should use it. As @degenerate said too, it is **really bad practice**, because PHP parser expands the code above using `@` operator to code snippet like following:

```
$old = error_reporting(0);
ultimateFunction($thisVariable);
error_reporting($old);
```

Additionally use of this operator might slower the application.

Comment: I down voted this for recommending the use of error suppression. It is bad practice and worse advice.

Comment: @vascowhite I have edited the post adding mention about it. Don't it additionally slower application, too?

Comment: Pointing it out as bad practice does not make the recommendation to use it any better.

Comment: @vascowhite And how can I edit the post to not be a recommendation of best practice? May I prepend _Use_ with _You can_?

Comment: In my opinion it should not be offered as a solution at all as it isn't really. The error is still there, it is just suppressed. I think that this answer and the other saying the same should be deleted.

Comment: @vascowhite Yes, you are right, there is still an error behind, but PHP users have to at least _know_, that there is kind of possibility in PHP (not saying they should use it, that really no).